# change the opacity of another image inside of another div by hovering over another div image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Is this too complicated to achieve?  Hopefully my question or title makes sense.  Essentially I have two divs - one is  and the other is .  I have 12 images inside of each div that I thought I attached IDs to.  I'm still much of a noob to web coding so perhaps I'm labeling them wrong.  But here's my goal, whenever you hover over artwork1, the opacity of artwork1 and button1 should change simultaneously.  And the effect needs to be achieved the other way as well (ie hover:button1 should change the opacity of artwork1).  Below is my code to explain my case further:

`<html>`
`<body>`
`<div id="buttons">`

```
<a href="..." id="button1"><img src="..." class="spaced"(to spaced the buttons)></a>
<a href="..." id="button2"><img src="..." class="spaced"></a>
```

`<div id="artwork">`

```
<a href="..." id="artwork1"><img src="..." class="mainbuttons & greydout"</a>
<a href="..." id="artwork2"><img src="..." class="mainbuttons & greydout"></a>
```

The 'mainbuttons' class is for spacing between the 12 images.  And the greydout class is to alter the hover effect already in place - going from opacity 0.3 to 1.
I've tried to research some javascript as I'm thinking that's the most proper solution.  My javascript I've tried to use is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#button1").mouseenter(function(){
       $("#artwork1").addClass("opac_art");
   });

   $("#button1").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#artwork1").removeClass("opac_art");
      $("#artwork1").addClass("greydout")
   });
});
```

One more thing to consider is that I have multiple scripts running for various functions:
1) a redirect script that will redirect mobile viewers to the mobile site;
2) a respond script that reformats the viewport to whatever the viewer's resolution browser size is set to.

I have the jQuery loaded up at the top of the document, but could there be conflict with the other scripts running on the html page?

I've even tried going the CSS route and I can barely get the divs to interact with each other.  The closest I've come is when I hover in the button div, I can alter artwork 1, but not as specific as I'm aiming for.  I hope all this makes sense, and thanks in advance for reading all this and trying to help me through this huge roadblock to getting my site up.

Comment: It would be really great if you could set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this problem.

Comment: I'm too new at web coding to even understand what I'm doing, let alone a jsFiddle. Ha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

Add a class to your buttons (galleryButtons) and to your images in the other div.

First of you do not really need the wrapping with the a tag
Add classes to your button elements and artwork.

```
<div id="buttons">
    <img id="gbutton1" class="galleryButtons" src="button.png" />
    <img id="gbutton2" class="galleryButtons" src="button.png" />

<div id="artwork">
    <img id="artwork1" class="artworkImage" src="art1.jpg" />
    <img id="artwork2" class="artworkImage" src="art2.jpg" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    var intID;
    $(".galleryButtons").hover(function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.id);
        var id = e.target.id;
        intID = id.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
        $("#artwork" + intID).addClass("opac_art");
    }, function () {
        $("#artwork" + intID).removeClass("opac_art").addClass("greydout");

    });
    $(".artworkImage").hover(function (e) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        intID = id.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
        $("#gbutton" + intID).addClass("opac_art");
    }, function () {
        $("#gbutton" + intID).removeClass("opac_art").addClass("greydout");

    });
});
```

All for you in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/et6tD/4/

It can be made simpler with selecting smarter, but I wanted you to see the relation in the element  better. When you hover over an element, the element that causes the event is send to the function. This event contains information. Like e.target.id will hold the id of that element.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: Instead of using a regex to parse out the ids, why not take advantage of `data` attributes to declare relations between a button and an artwork? Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr8Bj/2/) to see what I mean (built from Xenolithic's jsFiddle).

Comment: Just like the tried solution above, I couldn't get this to work as well.  Shouldn't I name the #artwork above to the designated class I have so that I can link up the opacity changes for button1-artwork1; button2-artwork2; etc.  I'm sorry, but I am very new to all of this.

Comment: Well.. I can't see how your css is working. You could see if manually adding them to the elements is creating the effect  you want.

As far as your elementsand buttons go:

`<a href="..." id="button1" class="galleryButton">
<a href="..." id="artwork1" class="galleryImage">`

Of course you should target the element you want to alter the style form. I will edit the original post.

Comment: Finally! It's alive!  Thank you for your tremendous help.  I'm such a noob that I didn't realize that I needed  to add another <script> line after running the jQuery code.  And after some final tweaking, I've achieved the result I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding of your question, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#one").hover(function()
    {
        // Changes the opacity of the first image
        // as well as the corresponding link from
        // 1 to 0.3.
        $("#artone").css({ "opacity": "0.3" });
        $(this).css({ "opacity": "0.3" });
    });

    $("#two").hover(function()
    {
        $("#arttwo").css({ "opacity": "0.3" });
        $(this).css({ "opacity": "0.3" });
    });
});
```

And the HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#" id="one">Link one</a>
    <a href="#" id="two">Link two</a>
</div>
<div id="artwork">
    <img src="" id="artone" class="spaced">
    <img src="" id="arttwo" class="spaced">
</div>
```

Couple extra things -

Make sure you actually link jQuery into your page's header, I didn't see it above:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

That's from Google's CDN, but you can do it locally, of course.

---

`<a href="#" id="artwork1"><img src="#" class="mainbuttons & greydout"></a>`

When listing classes for an element, you don't add an ampersand (&), you just leave them with a space in between.

`<a href="#" id="artwork1"><img src="#" class="mainbuttons greydout"></a>`

Comment: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr8Bj/1/) to show what it looks like. I swapped the images with a div for simplicity.

Comment: I've loaded up the jquery - got it from this source, in this format: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">.  I tried the one you have there but there was an error in the code according to DW.  Anyhow, I tried the solution and couldn't get it to work.  I'm wondering if the jQuery is working at all as there might be something I haven't thought through yet to make sure its working properly.

Comment: I assume "DW" is DreamWeaver, and I'm not sure if DW's WYSIWYG will pull files from the Internet. If you're doing everything locally, you could just download the actual jQuery .js file and link it `src="/path/to/the/file.js"`. A simple test to see if it's working would be `$("body").html("Hi!");` - Make sure to wrap it in the `$(document).ready(function() {` though!.

Comment: Yeah, DW is Dreamweaver - still learning the language of the land here.  This is probably the dumbest question you've heard on this board but what is that function supposed to do when I run the test?  I'm not getting any kind of response to let me know that it's working.

Comment: It just inserts "Hi!" into the `<body>` tag, so essentially it'd be like: `<body>Hi!</body>`

Comment: Thanks for your help too.  Your help combined with Daniel's below helped me finally achieve the look I was going for.

Comment: Not a problem. I answered the other question you had going as well, so check that out, too!

Comment: Yep.  I had figured that out earlier last week.  Mostly on my own I might add :)  Thanks though, nonetheless.